# In Apache Maven, is it possible to control the order in which files are added to an archive?

Tags: maven

Using Apache Maven and a plugin which creates archives (such as the `maven-war-plugin`), when using a wildcard to include files, is it possible to specify the order in which they are included?

We have observed that different versions of Maven, on different operating systems, can sometimes assemble archives with the files in non-deterministic order.

To clarify the desired answer, let's say I always want the files in the archive to be assembled in alphanumeric order. This should be consistently done across different platforms or Maven versions.

*Note, I am intentionally leaving out the "why does this matter" piece of the question, I am curious and thought others might wonder about the answer as well*

Comment: I would say. definitely not. The real question is: Why does this matter as you already mentioned.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't matter isn't really relevant to the question, but for curious readers, I ran into an application code issue involving import of many Spring context files, using a pattern like **/*.xml - two different machines were placing these files in the JAR in different orders, leading to different behavior. Obviously, this was an easy issue to resolve by modifying the code, but I was curious how (or if) it _could_ have been solved using Maven assembly-time rules or filters.

Comment: It's also important for having [reproducible builds](https://reproducible-builds.org/).